# why RunTimeExceptions need not to be caught at compilation time

Tags: java

Checked exceptions need to be caught or declared to be thrown at compilation time but runtimeexceptions need not ...why we give important only to checked exception ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Java, the original inventors of the language wanted to distinguish between common types of exceptions, which may occur in a program. They came up with these three types:

- Checked exceptions are used for errors, which may occur at run-time and are expected (sort of), for example, `IOException`. When doing file or network I/O, for example, an error may occur at any time (disk full, connection lost, etc.) The programmer has to be aware, that any operation called may fail at any time, and thus, the language enforces this kind of awareness by forcing the programmer to do something about the exception.
- Unchecked exceptions are used for programming errors, such as `NullPointerException`, `IllegalArgumentException`, etc. These errors are usually the result of an oversight of the programmer, and constitute bugs in the program. They should not be handled by most parts of the code, as all guarantees about the state, the program is currently in and its consistency, are gone. One of the distiguishing features of a run-time exception is, that it is *unexpected* (you don't really expect there to be a bug in your program, right? -- except on the general level of "of course, I would not bet my life on this program being bug-free")
- Errors, from which a recovery is hardly possible, such as `OutOfMemoryError`, `AssertionError`, etc. These exceptions are the really bad ones. These guys are usually never handled, and if they occur, will cause the program to crash.

Of course, in practice, many application will handle run-time exceptions (at least by logging them), and even `Error`s. And frameworks like Spring tend to blur the distinction further by making all exceptions unchecked (i.e., run-time exceptions) anyway. Interestingly, checked exceptions were considered for inclusion in C# and omitted, because they add a heavy burden on the programmer. Opinions vary on that topic, even today.

Comment: *"Opinions vary on that topic, even today."* - very tactfully put :-)

Comment: so checked exceptions are generated because of jvm errors and unchecked exceptions are generated because of program errors

Comment: @saravanan: Not exactly. It's more to do with whether the programmer *must* expect an operation to be able to fail (I/O, etc.) or not (attempt to dereference null pointer, heap full, etc.) This has nothing to with the JVM. In a way, all exceptions can be thought of as being generated by the JVM

Answer (score 2):

Taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling

> Unchecked exception types should not
>   be handled except, with consideration,
>   at the outermost levels of scope.
>   These often represent scenarios that
>   do not allow for recovery:
>   RuntimeExceptions frequently reflect
>   programming defects,[19] and Errors
>   generally represent unrecoverable JVM
>   failures. The view is that, even in a
>   language that supports checked
>   exceptions, there are cases where the
>   use of checked exceptions is not
>   appropriate

Clearly mentions that it represents **scenarios that do not allow for recovery**

Answer (score 2):

The division gives you flexibility: when thinking what kind of exceptions to throw, you should throw checked exceptions only when the application can reasonably recover from them (for example: "can't write file" is rarely a good reason to crash; rather, let's show a message to the user). Runtime exceptions are supposed to be fatal (programming errors), so it's better to let the program crash right away.

It was supposed to be a good idea. But it's just too complex in practice. The core problem is that the *library and language designers*  are supposed to decide what kind of errors are fatal to an *application* (which doesn't even exist at that time!).

Did you know that while `1 / 0` results in `ArithmeticException`, `1.0 / 0` is a perfectly legal `Infinity`? Obvious - or not... And [java.text.Format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Format.html) is supposed to convert an arbitrary object to `String`, but for some reason it throws an unchecked exception (`IllegalArgumentException`) if the object to be converted is somehow wrong type (e.g. `null`), so in practice you must *remember*  to write a try-catch block whenever you use `Format`. Obviously someone thinks that converting nulls to strings is a fatal programming error. I would rather return an empty string. Your mileage may vary. The JDK is full of this kind of weird choices, and it clearly shows the problem of choosing between checked vs. unchecked.

This problem has made many people advocate unchecked exceptions only. I think it's just silly; most exceptions *should* be taken care of, because they signal something important. If I was a language designer, I would make all exceptions checked, but instead of a try-catch -block, one could use a plain annotation to say "I don't care about this exception" (which essentially would convert that checked exception into a runtime exception). This would give the benefits of checked exceptions (nothing goes unnoticed unless explicitly told so) AND the benefits of unchecked exceptions (no heavy try-catch blocks all around). It would be the application programmer's call to decide what's fatal and what's expected.

Of course, you *can* catch runtime exceptions if you want to. A plain `catch(Exception ex)` does it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the name of the exception "RunTime".

At compile time the compiler can see exactly what and where things can go wrong with most of your code.

However some objects/values can only be evaluated at run-time and unfortunately the compiler cannot foresee this.

e.g. casting an object to int, when it is in fact a string. You can only determine it at run-time. Thus a run-time exception will be thrown

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the common RuntimeExceptions:

- ArithmeticException
- ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
- ClassCastException
- EmptyStackException
- IllegalArgumentException
- IllegalMonitorStateException
- NullPointerException
- UnsupportedOperationException

Practically speaking: Most of those exceptions can occure everywhere and are most likely a programmers error, and as such are only needed to be handled in some kind of bug reporting handler. Other Exceptions show problems with the environment of the JVM, and need to be handled, because they cannot be guaranteed no to be thrown be the program alone.

Answer (score 1):

if exception occurred at runtime then immediately JVM creates exception object and that object message is printed on console.

```
unchecked exceptions are occurred due to poor logic of our program.so program will be terminated abnormally.but JVM will not be halted.so JVM creates Excpetion object.
```

if we consider checked exceptions,for example,if we want to load some external file into our program , JVM is responsible for that.so,if any problems are occurred while that file is loading then JVM will be halted .so,then who creates exception object.this is the problem with checked excpetions .

to over come above problem we have to handle checked excptions at compiletime using throws keyword.

if you handle checked exception the following is done 
-- JVM executes one by one statement , when it identifies throws keyword followed by checked exception then it creates checked exception object.so,when the exception is occurred then already created exception object is used to print the exception information on the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
    When you can handle the recovery of the state of Object , go for Checked Exception.
    When you cannot handle the recovery go for UnCheckedException.
    Mostly API developers go for Runtime Exception , 
   they do not want to enforce handling exception by the user, 
   since they themselves do not know how to handle it
```

Answer (score 0):

Runtime exceptions can occur anywhere in a program, and in a typical one they can be very numerous. Having to add runtime exceptions in every method declaration would reduce a program's clarity. Thus, the compiler does not require that you catch or specify runtime exceptions (although you can).